# NodeJS - Проблема с объектом

Tags: node.js, steam

Использую модули:

- backpack.tf
- steamcommunity
- steam-tradeoffer-manager
- mysql (это неважно)

При новом обмене я получаю Market Hash Name предмета. Затем обращаюсь к ценам из backpack.tf, где они в таком формате:

```
   'Australium Rocket Launcher':
   { defindex:
      [ 18,
        205,
        15006,
        15014,
        15028,
        15043,
        15052,
        15057,
        16005,
        16017,
        16028,
        15081,
        15104,
        15105,
        15129,
        15130,
        15150 ],
     prices: { '11': [Object] } },
```

И ищу цены для предмета. 
Итак. Я получаю название предмета (в данном случае ):

> Secret Saxton

Но при обращении к объекту через `data.response.items[переменная с названием предмета]` не получается (выдает 0), хотя если вбить вручную `data.response.items['Secret Saxton']` все получается.
При этом и 'Secret Saxton' и переменная с названием предмета - строка.

Answer (score 0):

Всё нормально, я просто получал вот это:

```
[ { value: 2.33,
currency: 'metal',
difference: 0.6149999999999998,
last_update: 1553302401,
value_high: 2.44 } ]
```

Поэтому-то и не работало.